# Working with negative times in excel

Tags: time, excel, vba

I use a Macro to retrieve data from a SP and then place it in a spreadSheet, in one column I have multiples values of times (h:mm), some of them positives (12:23) and some negatives (-1:23), now I want to have an average of time, but I'm having an error with the negatives values.

I found in the web that using the 1904 date system, fix the issue, but not in my case since I place a negative value in a cell, no a result from substract two time cells.

for instance, the 1904 date system works in this case:

```
A:1 -> 3:23 
A:2 -> 4:23 
A:3 -> =A1-A2 -> -1:00
```

My case:

```
A:1 -> 3:23
A:2 -> -4:23 (built in code behind as string value and placed it in the cell)
A:3 -> =A1-A2 -> ERROR
```

Any help will be appreciated

EDIT:

Here is how I set the cell's value:

```
.Cells(i, k).Value = NetWorkhours(.Cells(i, 19).Value, .Cells(i, 20).Value, True)
```

Where NetWorkHours return a variant with the difference between two dates but work hours only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes 1904 date system fixes this issue. However it is not advisable to use this if your workbook contains links to other files as you can get unexpected results.

How are you placing the -ve values in Cell A2? I just copy a formula result (to get the -ve value) and paste as values in Cell A2 and it works perfectly.

Also when you do A1 - A2 then what exactly happens is

3:23 - (-4:23) => 3:23 + 4:23 => 7:46

**FOLLOWUP**

It is the way you are inputting the values makes it a problem :)

Instead of A1 - A2 try this formula instead

```
=IF(LEFT(A1,1)="-",VALUE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)-1)),VALUE(A1))-IF(LEFT(A2,1)="-",VALUE(MID(A2,2,LEN(A2)-1)),VALUE(A2))
```

Comment: Im placing the -ve by building a string in the code behind, that's why it doesn't work, when I click on that cells, it appears as a text value, not a time one

Comment: Exactly :) It will not work if it is a string value. Do this, 'copy and paste as value' a formula result and format that cell as "h:mm". You will notice that in the formula bar, it appears as "-4:23:00 AM" and not "-4:23".

Comment: Siddharth, remember that I retrieve those values from code behind and then I place them in a spreadsheet; that spreadsheet has already the right format "h:mm", but when the data come, the positive times appear as "4:23:00 AM" but the -ve ones as "-4:23". That's my issue.

Comment: jejeje nice solution Siddharth, it worked! thank you so much :)